# How show an array of images using the urls in react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

how to display an array of images in react native, the images use URLs, I tried this, but the images are not showing, the console log is showing the images URLs, but for some reason, the images aren't showing

```
{
      this.props.user.map((images) => {
        images.photos.map((image) => {
          console.log(image)
          return (
            <View>
              <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: image }} />
            </View>);
        })
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the inner `map`, also don't forget to add `key` when iterating over arrays

```
{this.state.user.map(images => (
  images.photos.map(image => (
    <View key={image}>
      <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: image }} />
    </View>
  ))
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a code snippet that works, please check [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/render-images-array)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return array.map((image) => {
      console.log(image)
      return (
        <View>
          <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 300 }} source={{ uri: image.download_url }} />
        </View>);
    });
  }
}
```